# Update a table with a group by of the table's own data

Tags: sql-server

Hope I explained that correctly. Here is some sample code. I want a count of rows where the values in a couple of the columns match.

```
DECLARE @myTemp TABLE
(
        Author varchar(20),
        Title varchar(25),
        MediaType varchar(5),
        ItemCount int NULL
)

INSERT INTO @myTemp (Author, Title, MediaType) VALUES ('Heinlein','The Roads Must Roll', 'CD')
INSERT INTO @myTemp (Author, Title, MediaType) VALUES ('Heinlein','The Roads Must Roll', 'Book')
INSERT INTO @myTemp (Author, Title, MediaType) VALUES ('Heinlein','Time Enough for Love', 'Book')
INSERT INTO @myTemp (Author, Title, MediaType) VALUES ('Asimov','The Foundation Trilogy', 'CD')
INSERT INTO @myTemp (Author, Title, MediaType) VALUES ('Asimov','The Foundation Trilogy', 'Book')
INSERT INTO @myTemp (Author, Title, MediaType) VALUES ('Asimov','I Robot', 'CD')
INSERT INTO @myTemp (Author, Title, MediaType) VALUES ('Asimov','Nightfall', 'Book')
```

I'd like to be able to get data back out that looks like this.

```
Author               Title                     MediaType ItemCount
-------------------- ------------------------- --------- -----------
Heinlein             The Roads Must Roll       CD        2
Heinlein             The Roads Must Roll       Book      2
Heinlein             Time Enough for Love      Book      1
Asimov               The Foundation Trilogy    CD        2
Asimov               The Foundation Trilogy    Book      2
Asimov               I Robot                   CD        1
Asimov               Nightfall                 Book      1
```

Something like

```
UPDATE @myTemp 
SET ItemCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @myTemp GROUP BY Author, Title)
```

But that's obviously not right as that subquery returns multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sql server, you can use FROM in your update statement and link this table to itself to get a count for each Author , Title instance.

```
UPDATE @myTemp
SET ItemCount = bookcount
from @myTemp as m
inner join 
(SELECT Author, Title, COUNT(*) as bookcount
 FROM @myTemp
 group by author, title) as mt 
 on m.Author = mt.author and m.Title = mt.Title
```

Not sure I understand your results. It's more of an Item Total. There aren't 2 CD's for The Roads Must Roll for example.

Comment: Regarding my results. I'm looking for the count of a title regardless of media type. That's for the quick answer. It's just what I needed.